# Discord.js Tenor API error [Displaying image from Embed]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using the Tenor API to display a random gif in an embed in Discord.js. I did everything correctly, however, the image is not loading.

Here is my code:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
module.exports = {
    name: 'tenor',
    category: 'misc',
    aliases: ['gif', 't'],
    async execute(message) {
        const url = `https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q=Anime_Kiss&key=${process.env.TENOR}&limit=20`
        let response = await fetch(url)
        let mom = await response.json();
        const makerandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * mom.results.length);
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setImage(mom.results[makerandom].itemurl)
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]})
    }
};
```

Here's what comes up:

[image]

Comment: Add 
```console.log(mom.results[makerandom].itemurl) ```
before sending message to your code and check if url is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `itemurl` is not a direct link to the file, but the full URL to view the post on tenor.com. You should use the `media` key instead. It's an array of dictionaries with the [format](https://tenor.com/gifapi/documentation#responseobjects-gifformat) (like `gif`, `mp4`, `webm`, etc.) as the key and a [media object](https://tenor.com/gifapi/documentation#responseobjects-media) (with keys like `size`, `duration`, and `url`) as the value. It means you can get the URL of the gif image by using `results[<random index>].media[0].gif.url`.

I've updated your code, it works as expected now:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
module.exports = {
  name: 'tenor',
  category: 'misc',
  aliases: ['gif', 't'],
  async execute(message) {
      let url = `https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q=Anime_Kiss&key=${process.env.TENOR}&limit=20`;
      try {
        let response = await fetch(url);
        let { results } = await response.json();
        let randomResult = results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)];
        let { gif } = randomResult.media[0];
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setImage(gif.url);

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error');
      }
  },
};
```

[image]